# How to create a validation rule which restricts data entry from specific table

Tags: validation, ms-access

I am creating a data entry form and report on MS Access and I would like to create validation rules for some input text boxes that restricts data based on the data contained in another table.

For example: For the subdivision input field, data that can be entered must be equal to one of the items which is contained in the Subdivision table which contains a list of subdivisions such as:

- Los Angeles Sub
- San Bernardino Sub
- Riverside Sub
- Etc

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it within your design requirements to change any textboxes that need table validation to comboboxes? This is a problem comboboxes solve very well.

Answer (score 0):

If your form data is directly bound to the table that holds it, then you would use the `Before Update` event of each text box to perform any validation you wish using VBA. If your form is not bound directly to the table you can either use the `On Lost Focus` event to validate each text box individually or whatever process you use to push the data to the table and validate the entire form input.